# CF flag and OF flag after IMUL Instruction

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

In IMUL description, it says:

> The Carry and Overflow flags are set if the upper half of the product
> is not a sign extension of the lower half.

So I have some assembly code:

```
MOV AL, 48
MOV BL, 4
IMUL BL ; AX = 00C0h, AH = 00 is positive and AL = C0 is negative so CF = OF = 1

MOV AX, 0x8760
MOV BX, 0x100
IMUL BX ; DX:AX = FF87:6000, DX is negative and AX is positive so CF = OF = 1
```

but in this one:

```
MOV AX, 0xFFF6
MOV BX, 0x1FFE
IMUL BX ; in debug, the result is DX:AX = FFFE:C014, CF = OF = 1
```

both DX and AX are negative, then why CF and OF are set?

Answer (score 4):

Sign extension of the lower half means:

- take the highest bit of the lower half (AX) and repeat it for the appropriate size (=> gives 0000 or FFFF)
- Is this equal to the upper half? (DX=FFFE in your case)

  - yes => flags to 0
  - no => flags to 1. (because FFFE != FFFF)

Basically it tells you whether the whole result fit into AX or if DX contains some interesting bits of it as well.

Comment: In other words, CF and OF both report whether `cwd` would set DX to a different value or not.  That instruction sign-extends AX into DX:AX.  (Or for other operand sizes, `cdq` or `cqo`)